# How to import scss variable depends on included mixin

Tags: angular, sass, scss-mixins

i have the following structure in my angular project:

```
- modules
 -- foo-module
   -- foo-comp
- assets
 -- fonts
   -- Open_Sans
      ....
- scss
 -- partials
   -- _fontface.scss
   -- _variables.scss
 styles.scss
```

**styles.scss:**

```
@import "./partials/variables";

* {
  margin:  0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
    background-color: $color;
    font-family: $font-face;
}
```

**_variables.scss:**

```
@import "./fontface";

@include font-face(OpenSans, "../fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular", 500, normal, ttf);

$font-face: OpenSans, sans-serif;
$color: yellow;
```

**_fontface.scss:**

```
    // =============================================================================
// String Replace
// =============================================================================

@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: "") {
    $index: str-index($string, $search);

    @if $index {
        @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
    }

    @return $string;
}

// =============================================================================
// Font Face
// =============================================================================

@mixin font-face($name, $path, $weight: null, $style: null, $exts: eot woff2 woff ttf svg) {
    $src: null;

    $extmods: (
        eot: "?",
        svg: "#" + str-replace($name, " ", "_")
    );

    $formats: (
        otf: "opentype",
        ttf: "truetype"
    );

    @each $ext in $exts {
        $extmod: if(map-has-key($extmods, $ext), $ext + map-get($extmods, $ext), $ext);
        $format: if(map-has-key($formats, $ext), map-get($formats, $ext), $ext);
        $src: append($src, url(quote($path + "." + $extmod)) format(quote($format)), comma);
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: quote($name);
        font-style: $style;
        font-weight: $weight;
        src: $src;
    }
}
```

**comp.scss:**

@import '...../variables';

And now i want to use **_variables.scss** as import in my **comp.scss**. So it doesnt look as possible, because `@include font-face(OpenSans, "../fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular", 500, normal, ttf);` this mixin has an url doesnt depend on **comp.scss** url, so i have a corresponding error. And it looks good in style.scss (cause of `../` url)

I need this global variable **$font-face** for the future usage of multiple fonts, and i want to store em in one place.

Comment: This `@import '...../variables';` is no valid URL. Did you mean `@import '../../variables`?

Comment: i mean smth like 'blablabla/', now ive had an answer from @Martin Choraine, please, look at

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular 6 it seems you can use absolute import with `~`

```
@include font-face(OpenSans, "~src/assets/fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular", 500, normal, ttf);
```